# DNS MX Entry Problem - Wrong Mailserver is used

Tags: dns, email, cpanel, plesk, mx

There is a clients domain, let's name it `www.client-xyz.example`, which was hosted with a web space package on a web host. I created a new homepage which is located on my server and I pointed the A-Record to my servers IP so that the visitors reach my server over the IP. That's working fine and as excepted!

The problem is that the mail service, which is controlled by cPanel on the old host wont work now! It seems like all mail connections reach the wrong server. If I send a email to one of the email addresses it gets rejected by my server instead of using the SMTP server from the old host.

Which DNS Record can I use to adjust it?

Comment: Are you sure you used an `A` record rather than a `CNAME` record?   Using a `CNAME` record at the domain apex (no subdomain) isn't allowed.   If you try to do so, one symptom is that your email will break like this.

Comment: Maybe the MX Record is a CNAME of the A record and now points to the new server, instead of the old one? Or the MX record does not exist, and mail-servers use the a record instead. If you post the DNS record (anonymised) it would be easier to help you